# Permisos a archivos subidos con PHP

Tags: php

Este es mi codigo de súbida del archo.

```
if(empty($error)){
        $archivo = "/".$dni."_".$nombreArchivo;
        $ruta = $directorioSubida.$archivo;
        $consul=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM archivos where guardar = ?");
        $consul->bindParam(1,$archivo);
        $consul->execute();
        $num = $consul->rowCount();
        if($num>0){
            $ruta = $directorioSubida."/(".$num.")".$dni."_".$nombreArchivo;
        }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $ruta)){

        $consult= $conn->prepare("INSERT into archivos values(null,?,?,?,?)");
        $consult->bindParam(1,$nombre);
        $consult->bindParam(2,$ruta);
        $consult->bindParam(3,$archivo);
        $consult->bindParam(4,$dni);
        $consult->execute();
        if($consult){
            //header("Location: subidaarchivos.php");
            chmod($ruta,0777);
            echo substr(sprintf("%o",fileperms($ruta)),-4);

        }

    }

}
```

Este es mi elemento de eliminanción del archivo subido

```
  if(isset($_REQUEST['eliminararchivo'])){
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $eliminar = $conn->prepare("DELETE from archivos where idarchivo = ?");
    $eliminar->bindParam(1,$id);
    $eliminar->execute();
    if($eliminar){
        $select = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM archivos where idarchivo = ?");
        $select->bindParam(1,$id);
        $select->execute();

        $fila1 = $select->fetch();
        $ruta = $fila1[2];
        $numero = strlen($ruta);
        $ruta = substr($ruta, 1,$numero);
        $ruta = "..".$ruta;
        unlink($ruta);
    }
  }
```

El problema es que al eliminar con php con ***unlink*** me pone:
"**unlink(..)**: Permission denied"
Sabeis el motivo o alguna solución.Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola una pregunta el programa lo estas ejecutando sobre un servidor linux o windows. Y lo otro que veo es que no estas colocando la parte del código donde estas usando el **unlink**

Comment: estoy con el servidor xampp en windows.Ahora lo coloco

Comment: Si por que me dices que el problema lo tienes al eliminar con **unlink** pero no lo veo en tu código.

Comment: ya está subido lo de unlink

Comment: Cual es el contenido que tiene la variable ruta si puedes imprime la con un echo y mira ver si te esta devolviendo la ruta correcta en donde estas guardado el directorio con el nombre del fichero si puedes por favor coloca ese resultado también en la pregunta

Comment: vale no me la imprimia por el orden de las consultas.

Comment: Es decir que la variable **ruta** esta vacía

Comment: si primero me lo eliminaba y entonces no me borraba el archivo

Comment: Si quieres borrar un archivo que tienes la referencia en la bd, Primero tienes que borrar el archivo y después la referencia en la bd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás buscando es el método [`chmod`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.chmod.php). Podrías darle los permisos una vez subido el fichero de la siguiente manera:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], $ruta);
chmod($ruta, 0666);
```

Este método tienes que ejecutarlo una vez subido, y antes de intentar eliminar con `unlink`.

Comment: Sí lo tengo después de subirlo. Y el unlink lo tengo en otro archivo, tengo añadido el código.